# Flutter HTTP Login page

Tags: flutter

I'm quite new to programming in Flutter, i'm trying to make an login function in Flutter. I would like to post a HTTP request to my server with an rest API. I have the rest API ready to go.

When the user is logging in it will receive an auth key or cookie. I want to store this cookie somewhere in flutter and use it elsewhere at post requests. When the user opens the app it needs to check if the cookie is still alive, if it is he should go right away to the dashboard of my application.

If the user logs out it should also delete the cookie.

Does somebody know a tutorial or github for this? I have seen lots of this but only in firebase and i really need a working one in just http requests!

[I made a small idea on how it should work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezENA.png)

Thanks in advance

Greetings,

Jente

Comment: Use the flutter `Cookie` class. Also see this answer for usage : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50299669/1274485

Comment: Save your token in shared preferences https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences and check it on splash screen -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073578/flutter-navigate-to-screen-without-delay/53084438#53084438
Here is a demo with a database: https://medium.com/@kashifmin/flutter-login-app-using-rest-api-and-sqflite-b4815aed2149

Answer (score 0):

What I'm using for my auth flow is [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) to save the session. After logging in, you can store the auth token depending on how your auth works.

```dart
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setToken('auth_token', authToken);
```

When the token is not needed anymore, you can delete the token in SharedPreferences.

```dart
// Either remove the specific SharedPref using the specific key
prefs.remove('auth_token');

// or clear the entire SharedPref instance
prefs.clear();
```

Here's a [sample template](https://github.com/omatt/flutter-navdrawer-template) on how I've implemented on my flow.